Vanishing $\mathrm{Tor}^1_{\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}}(\mathcal{O}_Y(Y),\mathcal{O}_X)$ for hyerpersurfaces $X$ and $Y$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$
Let $X$, $Y$ be hypersurfaces of $\mathbb{P}^n$ $\textbf{(not necessary meets transversally)}$.
I read from some literature that $\mathrm{Tor}^1_{\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}}(\mathcal{O}_Y,\mathcal{O}_X)=0$ can be definition for the $X$ 'transaversally meet' with $Y$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$.
Since $\mathrm{Tor}^{R}_1(R/I,J)\cong\frac{I\cap J}{IJ}$ for $I, J$ that ideals of a ring $R$, it seems reasonable. But if I think about $\mathrm{Tor}^1_{\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}}(\mathcal{O}_Y(Y),\mathcal{O}_X)$ in the same setting, I wonder that whether it is always $0$ or not. This question comes from a standard short exact sequence for $Y$ ;
$$
0\to\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(-Y)\to\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}\to\mathcal{O}_{Y}\to 0
$$
that yields
$$
0\to\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}\to\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(Y)\to\mathcal{O}_{Y}(Y)\to 0
$$
and then tensoring $\mathcal{O}_X$, we get
$$
0\to\mathrm{Tor}^1_{\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}}(\mathcal{O}_{Y}(Y),\mathcal{O}_X)\to\mathcal{O}_X\to\mathcal{O}_{X}(D)\to\mathcal{O}_{D}(D)\to 0
$$
where $D=X\cap Y$, viewed as a divisor of $X$.
My question is that : the term $\mathrm{Tor}^1_{\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}}(\mathcal{O}_{Y}(Y),\mathcal{O}_X))$ is always vanishing without any additional(geometrical or algebrical) conditoin?
Please some help or recommend a book related to this problem.

What is your question?

@Sasha Sorry for my unclear sentence I wrote before. My question is that the torsion, $Tor^1(O_Y(Y),O_X)$ term is always zero without any additional condition for the hypersurfaces $X$ and $Y$ (like transversally meet).

It is nonzero if and only if $X$ and $Y$ have a common irreducible component.

@Sasha Thank you. It's very helpful. Would you recommend some textbook or lecture note related to this question? (include divisors, intersection of varieties with some homological method)
